# Posted value is not getting in the where clause with json highcharts-php and mysql

Tags: php, json, highcharts, google-analytics

I have two files
1. Analytics.php
2. data.php

Analytics.php Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },

            /*tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                }

            },*/
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 1) +' %';
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Documents',
                data: []
            }]
        }


        $.getJSON("data.php",  function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });

    });
```

Html Code:

```
 <form method="post" name="havoc" >
     Search <input type="text" placeholder="Eg: Ronnie" name="authname_sa" value="">

    <input type="submit" name="search_authanalysis_sa" value="Search">
 </form>

   <?php
       if(isset($_POST['search_authanalysis_sa'])){
         $auth_sa =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['authname_sa']);
       }
   ?>



2. data.php Code

     <?php
       include 'connect.php';
       $df = $_POST['authname_sa'];

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT subj_area, documents, auth_name FROM subj_area WHERE  auth_name='$df'");

    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       $row[0] = $r[0];
       $row[1] = $r[1];
       array_push($rows,$row);
    }

       print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Here the chart is working fine. But the problem is in data.php file the php variable $df  has some value which is posted by the form. But when I try try to use that is where clause it is not getting that value.

But if enter the value manually like
$result = mysql_query("SELECT subj_area, documents, auth_name FROM subj_area WHERE  auth_name='Ronnie'");

As shown above if i enter the value directly as Ronnie then its working. What is the problem actually? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

can you please used **action**

```
<form method="post" name="havoc" action="data.php" >
```

Second Case :

```
WHERE auth_name='".$df."'"
```

Comment: I already used bro, but it will hang over in data.php file, it won't redirect to analytics.php , i have graph in analytics.php , even i redirect and check it but its not working. i echo the value and checked its showing the value correctly, but when i use it in where clause it is not working.

Comment: When I manually use WHERE auth_name='Ronnie', its working perfectly. Please help

Comment: then used WHERE auth_name='".$df."'"

Comment: No bro its not working, because the value is not posting, that is the problem, any other way to post the value.

Comment: try to use 'SELECT bla bla bla FROM bla bla bla WHERE auth_name=\''.$df.'\'';